# ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE in C:\wamp\www\justifiable\admin\admin.php on line 191

Tags: php, syntax-error

```
        <?php
include("ayar.php");
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["login"])){
echo "Bu sayfayı görüntüleme yetkiniz yoktur.";
}else{
echo '

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Yetkili Paneli</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/960.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/text.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/blue.css" />
<link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/blend/jquery.blend.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.sortable.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.dialog.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/effects.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.pack.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/excanvas.pack.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/iefix.css" />
    <script src="js/pngfix.js"></script>
    <script>
        DD_belatedPNG.fix('#menu ul li a span span');
    </script>        
    <![endif]-->
    <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/graphs.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<!-- WRAPPER START -->
<div class="container_16" id="wrapper"> 
<!-- HIDDEN COLOR CHANGER --><!--LOGO-->
  <div class="grid_8" id="logo">Ziyaretçi Defteri Yetkili Paneli</div>
    <div class="grid_8">
<!-- USER TOOLS START -->
      <div id="user_tools"><span><a href="#" class="mail">(20+)</a> Hoşgeldin Sn. <a href="#">Admin</a> |  <a href="#">Çıkış Yap(Güvenli)</a></span></div>
    </div>
<!-- USER TOOLS END -->    
<div class="grid_16" id="header">
<!-- MENU START -->
<div id="menu">
    <center><ul class="group" id="menu_group_main">
        <li class="item first" id="one"><a href="#" class="main current"><span class="outer"><span class="inner dashboard">Gelen Mesajlar</span></span></a></li>
        <li class="item last" id="eight"><a href="#" class="main"><span class="outer"><span class="inner settings">Ayarlar</span></span></a></li>        
    </ul></center>
</div>
<!-- MENU END -->
</div>
<div class="grid_16">
<!-- TABS START -->
    <div id="tabs">
         <div class="container">
            <ul>
                      <li><a href="#" class="current"><span>Gelen Mesajlar</span></a></li>

           </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- TABS END -->    
</div>
<!-- HIDDEN SUBMENU START -->
<div class="grid_16" id="hidden_submenu">
      <ul class="more_menu">
        <li><a href="#">More link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">More link 2</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#">More link 3</a></li>    
        <li><a href="#">More link 4</a></li>                               
      </ul>
      <ul class="more_menu">
        <li><a href="#">More link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">More link 6</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#">More link 7</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">More link 8</a></li>                                  
      </ul>
      <ul class="more_menu">
        <li><a href="#">More link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">More link 10</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#">More link 11</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#">More link 12</a></li>                                 
      </ul>            
  </div>
<!-- HIDDEN SUBMENU END -->  

<!-- CONTENT START -->
    <div class="grid_16" id="content">
    <!--  TITLE START  --> 
    <div class="grid_9">
    <h1 class="dashboard">Anasayfa</h1>
    </div>
    <!--RIGHT TEXT/CALENDAR--><!--RIGHT TEXT/CALENDAR END-->
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
    <!--  TITLE END  -->    
    <!-- #PORTLETS START -->
    <div id="portlets">
    <!-- FIRST SORTABLE COLUMN START --><!-- FIRST SORTABLE COLUMN END -->
      <!-- SECOND SORTABLE COLUMN START --><!--  SECOND SORTABLE COLUMN END -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!--THIS IS A WIDE PORTLET-->
    <div class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-header fixed"><img src="images/icons/user.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Latest Registered Users" /> Gelen Mesajlar</div>
        <div class="portlet-content nopadding">
        <form action="" method="post">
          <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="box-table-a" summary="Employee Pay Sheet">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th width="55" scope="col">Onayla</th>
                <th width="152" scope="col">Ad</th>
                <th width="118" scope="col">Soyad</th>
                <th width="125" scope="col">Email</th>
                <th width="145" scope="col">Mesaj</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Stephen C. Cox</td>
                <td>stephen</td>
                <td>20.06.2009</td>
                <td>Los Angeles, CA</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Josephin Tan</td>
                <td>josephin</td>
                <td>20.06.2009</td>
                <td>Los Angeles, CA</td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Joyce Ming</td>
                <td>joyce_m</td>
                <td>20.06.2009</td>
                <td>Los Angeles, CA</td>
               </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>James A. Pentel</td>
                <td>james_pent</td>
                <td>20.06.2009</td>
                <td>Los Angeles, CA</td>
                </tr>
              <tr class="footer">
                <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
<!--  END #PORTLETS -->  
   </div>
    <div class="clear"> </div>
<!-- END CONTENT-->    
  </div>
<div class="clear"> </div>

        <!-- This contains the hidden content for modal box calls -->
        <div class='hidden'>
            <div id="inline_example1" title="This is a modal box" style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
            <p><strong>This content comes from a hidden element on this page.</strong></p>

            <p><strong>Try testing yourself!</strong></p>
            <p>You can call as many dialogs you want with jQuery UI.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<!-- WRAPPER END -->
<!-- FOOTER START -->
<div class="container_16" id="footer">
Kodlama Tr Çeviri Entegre <a href="../index.htm">Kolerak8</a></div>
<!-- FOOTER END -->
</body>
</html>
<?php ';}?>
```

I take ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE in C:\wamp\www\justifiable\admin\admin.php on line 191 error. But ı cant see what'm ı missing please ı need emergencsy help!

Comment: You are **BADLY** abusing the php syntax. You should not be using such an insanely long echo. All you have to do is `?> long html here <?php ...` instead. Anything OUTSIDE of `<?php ... ?>` bracket pairs is considered output anyways.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

On line `7` You need to do this

```
else{
echo '
```

to

```
else{
```

On line `191` You need to do this

```
<?php ';}?>
```

to

```
<?php }?>
```

Remove `echo` as it is already very clear that in `else` condition it will show Html.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `echo`. It doesn't make sense. Dropping out of PHP mode is all that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't used the correct syntax right after opening the the single with echo  quote and then closes the php tag

```
<?php if(1=1){

?>

do what you want with your html 

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: good example +1 for you mate ;)

Answer (score 0):

Better anwser i think will be to remove line 7, and at line 191 change to:

```
<?php } ?>
```